# Kendo UI - Java script event handlers (code separation + parameters)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using a Kendo ui treeview-control in my ASP.NET MVC razor view. In the Kendo UI examples the java script event handlers are always embedded directly in the view (which I think is a bad practise). I guess this is only due to simplification, but I have now separated the JS event handlers in a separate JS file for the view in the "Scripts/views"-folder in a "myView.js"-file. Now I have the problem, that my resource-strings are not shown correctly anymore. My idea is to pass the resource-string as additional parameter in the view to the JS-event handler, but I don't know ho to do that. Below I have added my code examples.

View.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/views/myView.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
     .Name("treeview")
     .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)Model.MyTreeViewItemModel)
     .Events(events => events
         .Select("onSelect") // how to pass parameters to onSelect?
     )
)
```

myView.js:

```
function onSelect(e) {
     var node = this.dataItem(e.node);
     // ... here I do something with node which works fine
     addAlert("@Resources.MessageDeleteSuccess"); // here I call my addAlert function which worked in the view, but not after moving the function to the JS-file
}
```

To sum it up my questions are:

1. Is the way how I separate the JS event handlers from my view (in separate JS files) best practise or how should I do that?
2. How can I add parameters to event handlers like "OnSelect"?

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.telerik.com/forums/passing-arguments-from-grid-event:

> Currently sending additional parameters to the event handler is not
>   supported, however please note that in the handler you can access the
>   caller by using the "this" keyword

My experience with the event handler's "this" parameter (with a Kendo Grid) is that it provides almost no useful information. For example, I have no clue how to get the grid's UI elements from "this".

One workaround is to define a handler locally which will then call the handler in myView.js with the parameter you want. For example, your handler could be "viewOnSelect" and in View.cs, you'll have

```
function viewOnSelect(e) {
    onSelect(e, '@Resources.MessageDeleteSuccess');
}
```